# Running Instrument->leaks and debugger console at the same time in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My program is crashing when using the memory leak instrument in xcode (yet it is showing no memory leaks).  I would like to be able to run the debugger console at the same time to see what's happening.  Is this possible?  thanks

Comment: And does it crash during debugging?

Comment: No, it's not crashing when using the debugger alone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - in the simulator at least.

The way to do this is to first run your app in instruments, then stop the app (this just makes sure Instruments knows about your application and that Instruments is up and running).  Then restart the app in the debugger.

Now go back to Instruments, and select "attach to process" - selecting your application from the drop-down.  You can start recording now and the debugger will also be functional.

Comment: so anyone knows how to do this with the device itself rather than the simulator? the simulator doesn't help with testing stuff like bluetooth networking etc..

Comment: The process is exactly the same for a device - I forget why I mentioned the simulator.  In Instruments, you can attach to a process on a phone or any other iOS device in the same way you attach to a process on your computer. You just have to make sure the device is selected in Instruments (top left dropdown).  You also should run "Profile" from XCode first so Instruments properly can properly symbolicate your app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure it's possible, but if it is, you would do it by starting from Instruments or XCode, and then in the other one attach to the process. In XCode you do this by going to Run -> Attach to Process. In Instruments you do it by going to Choose Target -> Attach to Process, in a new window.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the simulator but not the device.  My App crashes running Instruments on the device, not the simulator, but it doesn't crash when using the debugger alone.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see NSLogs and other debug messages, you can open the Console app.